# Play/Pause button on headphones works for a time, then stops

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3, headset, headset-controls

I have a Galaxy Note 3, and the play/pause button on the wired headset only works for a short time.  Once I start playing music or whatever, with Ginko/Music/Play Music, the button works fine.  After listening to a song or two however, pushing the button has no effect and I have to pull my phone out to play or pause.  Has anyone else had this problem, or is it something I should be submitting for repair?

Thanks.